# Mouse pointer in win32 application on windows touch not visible

Tags: c++, winapi, touch

I am creating a win32 application which should work using windows touch also.
I need to show the mouse cursor when user is dragging his finger, which is currently invisible.
My code is working fine if I remove the checkbox of "Show user feedback" from windows touch options. To achieve this programmatically, I tried

```
    const BOOL value = FALSE;
    SetWindowFeedbackSetting(hwnd, flagToTurnOff[i], 0, sizeof(value), &value);
```

where

```
    flagToTurnOff[] = {
    FEEDBACK_TOUCH_CONTACTVISUALIZATION,
    FEEDBACK_TOUCH_TAP,
    FEEDBACK_TOUCH_DOUBLETAP,
    FEEDBACK_TOUCH_PRESSANDHOLD,
    FEEDBACK_TOUCH_RIGHTTAP,
    FEEDBACK_GESTURE_PRESSANDTAP
    }
```

but to no effect.
Is there any way to get this working without user to manually first edit windows options.

Comment: I don't have a touch device to test this on, but I am quite puzzled by the apparent claim that turning *off* a setting titled "show user feedback" would cause the mouse pointer to be shown when the user is dragging his finger. Are you sure you don't have that backwards?

Comment: Apparently, this option enables some windows inbuilt feedback to be shown to user like showing a rectangle on keeping finger at a particular point for a long time implying a right click. This is one example of feedback which is getting successfully removed by the above code.

Comment: Well, I don't know. [This blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141022-00/?p=43793) suggests that you're doing it correctly. I'm not sure where you're calling this code; make sure you're doing it early enough in the application's lifecycle.

Comment: I tried calling this code at 2 different places - between CreateWindow() & ShowWindow(), and inside handling of WM_CREATE message.

Comment: I have been able to repro the same behavior on dummy app creating just a window.